# How to manage puppet master and agent connectivity

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

As it is lab, we can add Ip address of agent to master hosts file.But if I have 1000 agents(partly windows and Linux machines), we can't add each and every agent to hosts file of master.How to manage there? I am from a windows background, please treat me as layman and guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the agent machines to DNS, so you can manage name - IP mappings via DNS.

Comment: Yeah, I do understand that, but all the servers in our network are windows based. ANd able to ping each other machines (windows) with hostnames, but not the Linux machines. How to fix this? I even installed wins but no use. I am using mostly ubuntu machines for linux

Comment: You need to set up DNS infrastructure in your network. I don't know how to do that on Windows servers.

Comment: Yes, there is already a dns infrastructure through which all the windows machines able to connect each other. Do we need a separate server infrastructure for Linux machines?

Comment: You need to set up Linux machines to use your existing DNS infrastructure then.

Comment: but it is not picking up, even after wins package

Comment: WINS has nothing to do with DNS. You need to set up your Linux machines DNS server settings to your internal DNS servers.

Comment: can you guide how to do that please

Comment: And to make it simple, we are using Workgroup environment, not AD.

Comment: I don't know if there are DNS services in your environment or not. I don't know Windows system well enough to know if they actually have DNS or not.